# Product's schema in marketplace - MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, nestjs

I am currently building marketplace in which many types of products will be sold. They are divided in categories - each category has unique set of parameters to describe product. For example, lets say that we are going sell clothes and medicines. Properties which would describe clothes are size, fabric etc.. For medicines on the other hand they would substance1(and its amount), substance2, effect, side effect etc. There will be many more different types. I am thinking what is the best way to create MongoDB schema so I it will be flexible enough to store all these information. I was thinking about something like:

```
import { SchemaFactory } from '@nestjs/mongoose';

import { BaseSchema } from '../../../common-schemas';
import { CommonSchema, OptionalProp, RequiredProp } from '../../../decorators';
import { BaseDBProperties } from '@shared/lib/mongo/interfaces';
import { ApiProperty } from '@nestjs/swagger';
import { Schema } from 'mongoose';

export interface IProductParameter extends BaseDBProperties {
  name: string;
  value: string | number;
}

@CommonSchema()
export class ProductParameter extends BaseSchema {
  @ApiProperty()
  @RequiredProp({ type: String })
  name: string;

  @ApiProperty()
  @RequiredProp({ type: Schema.Types.Mixed })
  value: string | number;

  @ApiProperty({ type: Number, required: false })
  @OptionalProp(null, { type: Number })
  substanceAmount: number;

  @ApiProperty({ type: String, required: false })
  @OptionalProp(null, { type: String })
  unit: string;
}

export const ProductParameterSchema =
  SchemaFactory.createForClass(ProductParameter);
```

Is it possible to choose schema on base of category's property of Product itself?

This is the first time I am encountering such a problem so maybe someone can give me any tip how to approach the problem. Thanks in advance.